# mysql unions with joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla, unions

How do I do mysql UNIONS with joomla 2.5:

> ```
>         $query = parent::getListQuery();
>   $query
>         ->select('*')
>         ->from('#__game_types')
>         ->where('published = 1')
>         ->order('price ASC')
>         ->union('ALL')
>        ->select('*')
>        ->from('#__dates')
> ```

I know union is not a method but I was just trying to show what I'd like to do.

Comment: see the following [*example*](http://www.joomla25upgrade.com/joomla-25-tutorials/31-jommla-with-other-database.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to my knowledge it's not in the [**Joomla doc**](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase) too. So what you can do is execute the query the other way like shown in the example below.

```
$query = "
  SELECT *
    FROM . . . ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadObjectList();
```